# How to get an editable cart at checkout with Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I always used `Commerce Kickstart` as a starting point for making e-commerce stores, but this time I opted to go with pure `drupal + commerce` modules.

One problem I have is that the cart view I get when I enter the checkout process is non-editable: it's just the list of items. The view used by the checkout is "Shopping cart form (Commerce Order)", and the cart uses `Shopping cart summary (Commerce Order)`. The latter has "remove" button in rows and an "update cart " link. Actually, I was able to replicate the elements of the formerin tha latter, save for the `update" cart` link.

I can get the one I am used to by going to `view cart`, but I do not get this one on chceckout. I tried to change settings at `admin/commerce/config/checkout/form/pane/cart_content`, but I can't  get the desired result.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not an answer, but debug idea: set up  Commerce Kickstart on a spare (probably virtual) server, and compare configurations.

Comment: yes, I am basically doing that now. What's annoying is that everything's here: I can access the relevant cart version, but I can't make it avaialable via checkout. I can't helpthinking there's a small switch somewhere that makes it work in a single click ;-)

Comment: What view are you seeing for the cart? And what is missing (i.e. qty, remove button, etc)? I have a running commerce site that doesn't use CKS, and my cart view is 'Shopping cart form', which is 'commerce_cart_form' in views, which shows quantity and a remove button in each line item row.

Comment: @DaveBruns just updated the description. " The view used by the checkout is "Shopping cart form (Commerce Order)", and the cart uses "Shopping cart summary (Commerce Order)". The latter has "remove" button in rows and an "update cart " link. Actually, I was able to replicate the elements of the formerin tha latter, ,save for the "update" cart" link."

Answer (score -1):

The module [Commerce cart form checkout pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_form_checkout_pane) does this very well.